# trouble finding file source in .rmd chunk when knitting .rmd from master .R file

Tags: r, knitr

Let's say I have a project directory called `testknit` (and I do, see [github](https://github.com/ericpgreen/Rcode/tree/master/testknit) for MRE), and inside this I have several subdirectories, including `scripts` where I keep `.R` and `.rmd` files.

In RStudio, I create a project and select this `testknit` directory so that when I open the project, the working directory is `mypath/testknit`.

Inside `testknit/scripts` I have a `master.R` file. If I want to source a file called `testsource1.R`, which is also in `testknit/scripts`, I can run `source("scripts/testsource1.R")` from within `master.R`.

```
library(knitr)
getwd()
# [1] "mypath/testknit"
source("scripts/testsource1.R")
```

So far so good.

But let's say I also want to knit a `.rmd` file called `test.rmd` that is located in `testknit/scripts`. I can run `knit("scripts/test.rmd")` from `master.R`.

My `test.rmd` file does the following:

````
```{r setup}
  library(knitr)
  opts_knit$set(root.dir='../')
```

```{r option1}
  source("scripts/testsource2.R")
```

```{r option2}
  source("testsource2.R")
```
````

Since `test.rmd` exists within `testknit/scripts`, I specify `opts_knit$set(root.dir='../')` in the first chunk so knitr knows that my root directory is really one level up.

When I open `test.rmd` in RStudio and click `knit HTML`, predictably, the `option1` chunk works and the `option2` chunk does not.

But when I try to knit `test.rmd` by running `knit("scripts/test.rmd")` from `master.R` instead of knitting from within the `.rmd` file, neither chunk option works. Both return an error that there is no file by that name.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't R find `testsource2.R` when knitting the `.rmd` file from the master `.R`?

See github link above for reproducible example.

**Update:**

As I noted below in the comments, I tried adding `wd <- getwd()` just before `opts_knit$set` and changed `(root.dir='../')` to `(root.dir=wd)`. So when I run `knit("scripts/test.rmd")` from `master.R`, the option2 chunk runs because the `wd` I added gets set to `mypath/testknit/scripts`. But if i open the `.rmd` file and run all chunks, `wd` is set to the root directory, `mypath/testknit`, and the option1 chunk runs.

I need the working directory to remain the project root. This does not seem like an elegant solution to me, but changing:

````
```{r setup}
  library(knitr)
  opts_knit$set(root.dir='../')
```
````

to

````
```{r setup}
  library(knitr)
  wd <- ifelse(basename(getwd())=="scripts", 
               gsub("/scripts", "", getwd()),
               getwd())
  opts_knit$set(root.dir=wd)
```
````

lets me run all chunks when in the `.rmd` file or `knit("scripts/test.rmd")` from `master.R`. It works, but it feels like I am taking the wrong approach.

Comment: don't know, but why don't you instrument your `.rmd` file further by adding `getwd()` calls in each chunk?

Comment: @BenBolker, I added `wd <- getwd()` just before `opts_knit$set(root.dir=wd)`. i don't understand why, but now when i run `knit("scripts/test.rmd")` from `master.R`, the option2 chunk runs because the `wd` i added gets set to `mypath/testknit/scripts`. but if i open the `.rmd` file and run all chunks, `wd` is set to the root directory, `mypath/testknit`, and the option1 chunk runs. do you know why `wd` changes from `mypath/testknit` to `mypath/testknit/scripts` when running `knit("scripts/test.rmd")` from `master.R`?

Comment: Perhaps you can make `../` an absolute path using `normalizePath('../')`. A relative working directory can be confusing to reason about (at least my head hurts after I read too many levels of relative paths :). BTW, when you Knit HTML in RStudio, RStudio first changes the working directory to the input Rmd file.

Comment: No problem. Just let me know if this blind shot in the dark works :)

Comment: yes! using just `opts_knit$set(root.dir=normalizePath('../'))` works for knitting the `.rmd` file from `master.R` and knitting to html or running all chunks from within the `.rmd`. i updated the github example. `test-b.rmd` now shows this. thanks! if you create an answer i'll select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Yihui: Perhaps you can make `../` an absolute path using `normalizePath('../')`. A relative working directory can be confusing to reason about (at least my head hurts after I read too many levels of relative paths :). BTW, when you Knit HTML in RStudio, RStudio first changes the working directory to the input Rmd file.

Me: yes! using just `opts_knit$set(root.dir=normalizePath('../'))` works for knitting the `.rmd` file from `master.R` and knitting to html or running all chunks from within the `.rmd`. I updated the [github example](https://github.com/ericpgreen/Rcode/tree/master/testknit). `test-b.rmd` now shows this. thanks!