# Working with knitr using subdirectories

Tags: r, knitr

I have a project folder, which is my working directory.  Let's call it *project*.  Under the *project* folder are 4 subdirectories:  `code`, `data`, `figures`, and `documents`.

I would like to put my `.Rmd` file in the `code` subdirectory.  I would like the figures to go into the `figures` subdirectory.  I would like the `.html`, `.md`, and `.docx` file(s) to go into the `documents` subdirectory.  I would like to read in my data from the `data` subdirectory.  Is this organizational structure possible?  I can't seem to get it to work.

I start with this to set the working directory to `project` because I understand that knitr looks to the folder with the `.Rmd` file and treats it as the working directory if this is not specified.

````
```{r setglobal, cache = FALSE, include = TRUE}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(root.dir = "..")
```
````

Then I try setting the figure path relative to the working directory.

````
```{r setchunk, cache=FALSE, include=TRUE}
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "./figures/")
getwd()
```
````

The working directory is correctly reported as `project`.  The data is correctly read from the `data` subdirectory. All output is rendered properly and all code runs.

````
```{r readdata}
crctx <- readRDS("./data/crctx.rds")
getwd()
*run lots of analyses here*
```
````

But the figures end up in the `project/code/figures` directory instead of `project/figures`.

I have also tried setting `base.dir` but that doesn't seem to change anything.  I added the parameter

```
base.dir = "./figures"
```

to the `opts_knit$set` list.  I even tried hard-coding the full path.  But nothing seems to be able to change this.

I am using R 3.10 and RStudio 0.98.953.  This is Mac 0SX 10.9.4.

Am I missing something?  And is there a way to put the output files in their own directory?

The reason this is important is that I would like our company to all use the same directory structure, and this will allow us to organize our projects better.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update:**

I realize that `opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "./figures/")` is incorrect.  I assumed that setting the root directory to the project folder using `opts_knit$set(root.dir = normalizePath("../"))` would make a global change to knitr, since that is what it is supposed to do.  And it does work for the data subdirectory, which can now be accessed with `"./data"` which allows the code to run.  However, the global setting doesn't apply to the figure output.  Therefore, the correct specification is `opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "../figures/")` -- using `../` instead of `./`.  I think Richie Cotton fixed this, and I didn't quite see it for a while.

I also used Terminal in OSX to create a symbolic link from `project/documents` to `project/code/figure` which is created by default by knitr.  With this, knitr looks to the right sub-subdirectory, but everything ends up in `projects/documents`.  That worked really well. I can't get R do create the symbolic link properly using file.symlink.  But it works fine in Terminal.  Go figure.

**update 2**:

I got the output files to work as well.  You have to use the knit command directly.  The text is below.

Knitr code to knit a markdown document with .Rmd in code/analysis and output in    output/reports:
    `knit("./code/knitr_file.Rmd", "./documents/knitr_output.md”)`

Pandoc code to convert .md file to .docx -- uses the same folder as the .md file
`pandoc("./documents/knitr_output.md", format = "docx”)`

## output styles (from knitr documentation)

`pandoc('knitr_output.md', format='html')  # HTML
pandoc('knitr_output.md', format='latex') # LaTeX/PDF
pandoc('knitr_output.md', format='docx')  # MS Word
pandoc('knitr_output.md', format='odt')   # OpenDocument`

Comment: See if [`normalizePath`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882198/trouble-finding-file-source-in-rmd-chunk-when-knitting-rmd-from-master-r-file) works for you.

Comment: I looked at the syntax, and I couldn't figure out what that was supposed to do.  But I can take another look.

Comment: An old question but this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51144177/4241780, it shows how to set the working directory to the main project folder when knitting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this. It assumes you have the 4 folders you listed inside the working directory `project`. It also assumes you have a `.csv` file called `myData.csv` in `data`.

When you knit the file, the plot will be saved in `figures`. At the end, the code looks for `html` files in `code` and moves them to `documents`. There's probably a better way to do this.

````
```{r setup}
  library(knitr)
  opts_knit$set(root.dir=normalizePath('../'))
  opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "../figures/", dev='pdf') # corrected path and added dev
```

```{r import}
  dat <- read.csv("data/myData.csv")
```

```{r plot}
  # pdf(file="figures/test.pdf")  # I do this in setup instead
  plot(dat)
  # dev.off()
```

```{r move}
  files <- list.files("code/")
  index <- grep("html", files)
  file.rename(file.path("code", files[index]),
              file.path("documents", files[index]))
```
````

Comment: I was able to achieve the figure part with `opts_knit$set(root.dir = "../");opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "../figures/test-")`. I tried `../` after seeing your post as `..` alone wouldn't work, grrr.

Comment: @eric Thanks. I understand normalizePath now, but this didn't work. I also tried to use `paste(getwd(), "/figures/", sep=""))` which is a manual way to `normalizePath()` and that didn't work.  I like the manual move.  I think maybe a call to `knit`, rather than clicking the button, might be able to set the output .md file.  Then a call to pandoc might work for setting the output .docx or .pdf file.  Have to look into this.

Comment: Hmmm, it works for me. Try grabbing the `/dir` folder from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/ericpgreen/Rcode/tree/master/dir). Make sure to `setwd()` to `/dir`. You should just be able to click `knit`.

Comment: Try knitting twice to get `html` file to move.

Comment: @EricGreen.  Thanks for your help.  I also found your post from late last year on a similar issue.  This all seems way too kludgy and hard to replicate on multiple computers and operating systems.  I am going to try one last thing by setting a symbolic link.  I will just create a figures subdirectory under code and then have that resolve to the figures directory under project.  Of course, when I try that, I can't get R to make the symbolic link properly.  But that seems like an easier path because it works with knitr instead of against it.

Comment: Thanks. In case it helps others, one thing that surprised me was that you need to have the opts_knit$set ... in a discrete chunk at the start of the knitr file. The directory change only takes effect from the next chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach. Place this at the start of your rmd file, and you will be able to use run code in line and using an RStudio project setup. The trick is to reset the knitr home directory to your project directory (mine is a couple in from the project directory hence the '/../../' but you get the idea). You also need to reset the figure and cache pathways otherwise outputs will end up in strange places.

If you play around with the setup below you can create the right file structure for your project needs.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
###--- Update the knitr working directory (R works from the project folder, knitr works in the rmd folder)
dd <- getwd()
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir= paste(dd,'/../../')) 

###--- Set some knitr defaults for all of the code blocks below. 
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE
                      ,error=FALSE
                      ,message=FALSE
                      ,cache=F
                      ,eval=TRUE
                      ,results='asis'
                      ,echo=TRUE
                      ,fig.ext="png"
                      ,cache.path = paste0(dd,'/cache/')
                      ,fig.path = paste0(dd,'/figures/')
                      ) 
```
````