# Controlling the output from knit2html

Tags: r, knitr

In my projects I have separate folders for documentation, plots, and data. I would like to run `knit2html` from the project root directory. In this case the input `test.Rmd` file is in the `doc/` folder and I would like the output to go to the same place. I can do this; however, the `test.md` file gets left in the parent directory (below).

````
library(knitr)

# set paths for knitr
opts_knit$set(base.dir=normalizePath(getwd()))
opts_knit$set(root.dir=normalizePath(getwd()))
opts_chunk$set(fig.path="figures/")

# create the output folder
dir.create("doc", showWarnings=FALSE)
dir.create("figures", showWarnings=FALSE)

# a minimal example
writeLines(c("```{r hello-random, echo=TRUE}", "plot(rnorm(5))", "```"), 
           "doc/test.Rmd")

# this works and outputs to test.html
knit2html(input = "doc/test.Rmd", output="doc/test.html")


list.files()
[1] "doc"     "figures" "test.md"

list.files("doc")
#[1] "test.html" "test.Rmd"
````

The `test.html` renders well, but of course the `test.md` file is in the wrong place. Alternatively, I could do this...

````
library(knitr)
library(markdown)

# set paths for knitr
opts_knit$set(base.dir=normalizePath(getwd()))
opts_knit$set(root.dir=normalizePath(getwd()))
opts_chunk$set(fig.path="figures/")

# create the output folder
dir.create("doc", showWarnings=FALSE)

# a minimal example
writeLines(c("```{r hello-random2, echo=TRUE}", "plot(rnorm(5))", "```"), 
           "doc/test2.Rmd")


knit(input = "doc/test2.Rmd", output="doc/test2.md")
markdownToHTML(file = "doc/test2.md", output = "doc/test2.html")

list.files()
[1] "doc"     "figures" "test.md"

list.files("doc")
#[1] "test.html"  "test.Rmd"   "test2.html" "test2.md"   "test2.Rmd" 
#correct output!

list.files("figures")
#[1] "hello-random-1.png"  "hello-random2-1.png"
#correct output!
````

Here `test.md` and `hello-random-2.png` go to the right place, but `test.html` is looking for `hello-random-2.png` in `doc/figures/hello-random2-1.png` and so it doesn't render correctly.

If I do `opts_chunk$set(fig.path="../figures/")` (as described here: [Working with knitr using subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585254/working-with-knitr-using-subdirectories)
), then the html is looking in the right place, but the `png` file is in the parent of the project root and the html does not render.

That the intermediate `test.md` doesn't go to the output path directory with `knit2html` makes me wonder whether it is working as intended.

Comment: The discussion here might be relevant: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/913