# Setting work directory in knitr using opts_chunk$set(root.dir = ...) doesn't work

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

My R project is structured like a package with directories `/R`, `/vignettes`, `/data` etc. In one of my Rmd docs in `/vignettes` I source a script which in located in `/R`. Inside this script I use `read.csv()` to load a file located in `inst/extdata/`.
The problem now is that by default the working directory inside the Rmd file is the directory where the file is located. Let's call it `/Users/Me/Docs/Proj/vignettes`. However in order for the R script to run the working directory needs to be the project's main directory (`/Users/Me/Docs/Proj`).
I tried to change the working directory in the Rmd file using `knitr::opts_chunk$set(root.dir = normalizePath("..")`. However apparently this *doesn't* change the working directory since if I call `getwd()` after it the output is still `/Users/Me/Docs/Proj/vignettes` whereas `knitr::chunk_opts$get("root_dir")` returns `/Users/Me/Docs/Proj`.

Here is a minimal example Rmd file:

````
```{r}
getwd()  # returns 'Users/Me/Docs/Proj/vignettes'
knitr::opts_chunk$set(root.dir = normalizePath(".."))  # should change the working directory to 'Users/Me/Docs/Proj'
getwd()  # again returns 'Users/Me/Docs/Proj/vignettes'
knitr::opts_chunk$get("root.dir")  # returns 'Users/Me/Docs/Proj'
```
````

I am using RStudio Version 0.99.435. Here is my session Info:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)  
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 (64-bit)  
Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)  

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] htmltools_0.2.6 tools_3.2.0     yaml_2.1.13     rmarkdown_0.6.1 digest_0.6.8
```

Any help is kindly appreciated. If you need more info post a comment to the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use `setwd()`?

Comment: From the documentation of `knitr::knit`: "It is
     not recommended to change the working directory via ‘setwd()’ in a
     code chunk, because it may lead to terrible consequences (e.g.
     figure and cache files may be written to wrong places). If you do
     use ‘setwd()’, please note that ‘knitr’ will always restore the
     working directory to the original one."

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[It is `knitr::opts_knit`](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) instead of `knitr::opts_chunk`.

Comment: This works in RStudio 1.0.143 for linux, but ONLY in the ```{r setup}...``` chunk. Just calling it ```{r initialization}...``` breaks it.

Answer (score 45):

Where you have an R project with nested subfolders, so that the .Rproj and .Rmd files are located in different folders, you can use the command `rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file()` to find and set the working directory to the Project's main folder  during Kniting (instead of the folder containing the rMarkdown code file).

So at a minimum use the following:

````
```{r setup}

knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())

```
````

inside the `setup` chunk.

See also [Automatically finding the path of current R project in R Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40709975/4241780)

Comment: This is ace! =)

Comment: This is the best way to go around this

Answer (score 23):

As [Yihui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui) has pointed out in his answer the mistake was simply that I used `opts_chunk$set()` instead of `opts_knit$set()`.

However it might be worth noting that the change of the working directory affects not the current but only the next chunk. So e. g. if you want to load data relative to the new working directory do that in the following chunk.

Answer (score 10):

Some details on implementation of setting work directory by `root.dir =`.
Although there already are some awesome answers by [Yihui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie) and [Tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4398177/tommy). I still got stuck in setting work directory. So I am trying to make a complete answer here.

1. From [knitr documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/objects/):

> Knitr’s **settings** must be set in a chunk **before any chunks** which rely on those settings to be active. It is recommended to create a knit configuration chunk as the first chunk in a script with **cache = FALSE and include = FALSE** options set. This chunk **must not contain any commands** which **expect the settings** in the configuration chunk to be in effect at the time of execution.

2. My code example:

In my case, the `.Rproj` and `.Rmd` files are located in the same folder.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE, cache = FALSE}
require("knitr")
## setting working directory
opts_knit$set(root.dir = "~/Documents/R/Example")
```
````

Comment: I had the same problem in setting working directory in a notebook (RStudio 1.2.1335, R 3.5.3), despite of the answers of @Yihui and @Tommy, due to the command `getwd()` inside of the _setup-chunk_. Thank you @Guannan for clarifying the solution!

Answer (score 3):

For me `knitr::opts_knit$set` worked with `root.dir` but didn't work with `echo = FALSE`

while

`knitr::opts_chunk$set` didn't work with `root.dir` but did work with `echo = FALSE`

Therefore,

I used both options in the setup chunk:

````
```{r settings, include = FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE
                      , comment = NA
                      , warning = FALSE
                      , error = FALSE
                      , message = FALSE
                      , tidy = TRUE)

knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = 'C:/...')

```
````

Comment: If you look here https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#package-options you'll find two blocks in the table of contents called "Chunk options" and "Package options". I've just realized that they are about your confusion. I had the same.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())` in the `setup` chunk to work with `knitr::include_graphics` (works fine for `source()` and `load()`) when the .Rmd file is located in a subdirectory upstream of other files. If you have the same problem, try:

```
library(here)
knitr::include_graphics(here("figs/figure.png"))
```

You could obviously use `../` too in these cases, but then the paths would not work directly in the console while debugging.

Source for the solution: https://community.rstudio.com/t/knittr-include-graphics-image-png-cannot-find-files/82959/2

Answer (score 0):

the below chunk is in need as the first one in a Rmd script.

```r
{r setup, include=FALSE, cache = FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(
  root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file()
  )
```

but, it does not work once in while. And i find it's possible caused by chunk output setting. `Chunk output inline` and `chunk output in console` are different. Make sure `Chunk output inline` and setup chunk will work.