# How to fix Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection in an R Notebook

Tags: r, rnotebook

I am learning R Notebook currently and I am having a path problem. I have made an R project and hosted all of my scripts and files in a folder containing the R project. I am trying to run:

Next, install libraries:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(CHNOSZ)
library(janitor)
```

Then import and merge the files using:

```
d <-list.files(path="./merge", pattern="*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  map_df(~read_csv(., col_types = cols(.default = "c")))

d
```

and the result is a tibble with 0 rows. Also,

```
write.csv(d,file="data_generated/FinalmergeAllCompounds_comb.csv")
```

throws the error Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection

When I run this as a normal script within the same project in Rstudio the script works just fine. I merge the .csv files without an issue and I can export it back out into my project directory with no problems.

It seems to be a conflict between RNotebook and the file path. How do I fix this?

Comment: The working directory for the R notebook is the directory where the file is hosted by default. You can change this in the knitr options. See the [Rmarkdown guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/notebook.html).

Comment: I have tried building an R notebook of a different script within the same same project directory, and it worked without these problems. Could it be a problem with the path="merge" (I have tried both path="merge" and path="./merge"?

Comment: Have you tried setting the working directory in the knitr options to see if that works?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question was to add:

```
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())
```

to the top of the notebook script based on csgroen's comment and this post [Setting work directory in knitr using opts_chunk$set(root.dir = ...) doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237310/setting-work-directory-in-knitr-using-opts-chunksetroot-dir-doesnt-wor)