# Problem turning ggplot into 3D graph (using rayshader)

Tags: r, ggplot2, 3d, rayshader

I am trying to turn a ggplot into a 3D plot using the rayshader package.
The ggplot is made with `geom_raster()` and works fine. This is how it looks like: [image: image attached]

Here is the code for the 2D plot. Although, I think that's not where the core of the problem is. Because as already mentioned, it works until here.

```
Plot = Score_image %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=as.numeric(x),
             y=as.numeric(y), fill= PC_1)) + 
  geom_raster()+
  theme_void()+
  scale_fill_viridis(na.value = "white")
```

Then I try to turn it into a 3D plot with `plot_gg(Plot)` and I receive the following error code:

```
Error in png::readPNG(paste0(heightmaptemp, ".png")) : 
  unable to open C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGQuKkm\file16dc6dd3339f.png
```

I have no idea what the error means and I didn't find anything online. I tried re-installing rayshader, but that didn't help. `plot_gg` works with also with other grahps that I have tried.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Maybe this answer has the solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61723961/10276092

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem and got resolved if instead of using theme_void() setting explicitly the elements as blank:

```
    Plot = Score_image %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=as.numeric(x),
             y=as.numeric(y), fill= PC_1)) + 
    geom_raster() +
    scale_fill_viridis(na.value = "white") +
    theme(legend.position = "none", 
        axis.line=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank()) # Clean Everything
```

Comment: Now it works, amazing!